# std::prev on std::array in a constexpr environment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++17, constexpr

I'm currently playing around with constexpr arrays, and i noticed that i can't get the following (valid) code to compile under MSVC 19.15.26726 with /std:c++17 or /std:c++latest:

```
#include <array>
using array_type = std::array<unsigned int, 3>;
using iterator_type = array_type::const_iterator;
constexpr array_type arr{ { 1,2,3 } };

constexpr iterator_type getIteratorBefore(iterator_type it) {
    return std::prev(it);
}

constexpr iterator_type test = getIteratorBefore(arr.end());
```

Ignoring all the highlighting errors and the error that says `std::array` is ambigous (seems to conflict with some weird `array()` function in the same file) that I'm getting from IntelliSense, I get the following compiler errors in the last line:

```
error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type
warning C4307: '+': integral constant overflow
```

It compiles fine in compiler explorer under gcc (x86-64 gcc (trunk)) and MSVC (x86-64 edit: MSVC Pre 2018 with /std:c++17 works) (didn't test the others).

I'm seriously out of ideas. The same code compiles when i put it in a main method, so it seems to be an issue with the constexpr scope.

Comment: Looks like a simple bug in MSVC. Should be compilable in C++17 mode.

Comment: C4146 and C4308 are comming up as warnings for me with the same version

Comment: @SergeyA Hmm seems you used the wrong compiler flag (see last output statement). It's /std:c++17 for MSVC. Doesn't matter though, because the version i mentioned in the post does not know the argument (?). It still thinks that we are in c++11, where non literal types were not allowed as constexpr function return types.

Comment: I compiled using `/std:c++latest` and the code compile and `test` points to 3.  The two errors you show come up as warnings for me but the code does compile.

Comment: @JulianWiesler I was referring to the code, not the compiler. The posted code is a valid C++17 code, and if MSVC fails to compile it, it is the bug in MSVC.

Comment: @NathanOliver thats interesting. I even checked for updates and created a new project but I'm still getting the two errors.

Comment: Interesting, with VS 15.8.1 it successfully builds in *release* configuration, but fails to build in *debug* configuration with the two errors.

Comment: Problem still exists in 15.9.0 Preview 1.0. Workaround for debug configuration is to `#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Repro

I can reproduce with VS 2017 15.8.1 and also with the latest 15.9.0 Preview 1.0 with /std:c++17 or /std:c++latest.

The problem only occurs if `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` does not equal `0`, typically in debug configurations.

## Cause

Spelunking through the STL code coming with MSVC, we can see that `_Array_const_iterator` has two different implementations depending on `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`. If `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` does not equal `0`, the iterator stores a base pointer to the array and an index variable `_Idx` of type `std::size_t`. Otherwise it stores just a pointer.

Part of the problem is caused by `_Array_const_iterator::operator+=()`, which is indirectly called by `std::prev()` with argument value of `-1`:

```
_CONSTEXPR17 _Array_const_iterator& operator+=(const ptrdiff_t _Off)
    {   // increment by integer
    _Verify_offset(_Off);
    _Idx += _Off;          //<-- error C4308
    return (*this);
    }
```

Error C4308 is caused because `_Idx` is unsigned, whereas `_Off` is signed and the actual (literal) value of `_Off` is negative.

Even simpler test case:

```
constexpr unsigned Test(unsigned x, int d) { x += d; return x; }
constexpr auto test1 = Test( 5, -1 );   //<-- error C4308
constexpr auto test2 = Test( 5, 1 );    //<-- OK
```

The assignment to `test1` produces error C4308 and warning C4307 too. I'm not sure about C4146, it's propably just a follow-up error.

MSVC seems to be more strict than GCC when signed and unsigned types are mixed in a `constexpr` context.

The solution would propably be for MSFT to change the type of member variable `_Idx` to `ptrdiff_t`. Feel free to file a bug :-).

## Workaround

Define `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0` or replace the `std::prev()` call:

```
constexpr iterator_type getIteratorBefore(iterator_type it) {
    return --it;
}
```

Comment: That helped, thanks. But why did they print just this error line? In normal template code you get at least a pseudo-stacktrace to the actual template code, that causes the error. Would be nice to have in constexpr as well.